# Как в стеке FragmentManager текущий видимый фрагмент сделать невидимым, а другой который уже есть в стеке - видимым?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, fragment-manager, fragment-transaction

использую для решения данной задачи вот такой код:

```
public void addTag(Fragment f, int id, String tag)
{
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(id, f, tag)
            .commit();
    currentTag = tag;
}
public void show(Fragment f)
{
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(currentTag))
            .show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(f.getTag()))
            .commit();
    currentTag = f.getTag();
}
```

т.е. при добавления фрагмента я сохраняю его тег как текущий в переменную currentTag чтобы с помощь неё позже сделать текущий фрагмент невидимым. Но
почему-то иногда (я ещё не разобрался при каких условиях)

```
hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(currentTag))
```

не срабатывает (или срабатывает неправильно). И поэтому соответственно currentTag перезаписывается на текущий хотя тот что должен был скрыться не скрылся и поэтому дальше код работает неправильно

помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо:

1. Найти уже добавленный (но сейчас скрытый) фрагмент в стеке:

   ```
   Fragment hidenFrag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("ВАШ_ТЕГ");
   ```
2. Заменить текущий найденным. Для этого есть метод `replace`

   ```
   FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, hidenFrag);
   //transaction.addToBackStack(null); //это позволяет (если не null передавать) возвратиться к предыдущему (например нажав "назад")
   transaction.commit();
   ```

Comment: Не подойдёт. Мне нужно не заменить, а оставить стек таким как есть. Необходимо сохранять состояние каждого фрагмента в стеке. Позже выяснил, что fragmentManager почему то неверно выполняет метод  findFragmentByTag. Буду дальше разбираться